# export and S3method in R NAMSPACE file

Tags: r, package

Here are some lines in the NAMESPACE file from a R package

```
S3method(diseq,table)
S3method(diseq,genotype)
S3method(print,diseq)
S3method(print,genotype)
S3method('==',genotype)
S3method('==',haplotype)
S3method('%in%',default)
S3method('%in%',genotype)
S3method('%in%',haplotype)
S3method('[',genotype)
S3method('[',haplotype)
S3method('[<-',genotype)
S3method('[<-',haplotype)
S3method(heterozygote,genotype)
S3method(homozygote,genotype)
#S3method(print,allele.count)
S3method(print,allele.genotype)
#S3method(allele.count,genotype)
#S3method(allele,genotype)
S3method(print,LD)
S3method(print,LD.data.frame)
S3method(print,summary.LD.data.frame)
S3method(plot,LD.data.frame)
S3method(print,summary.genotype)
S3method(plot,genotype)
S3method(order, default)
S3method(order, genotype)
S3method(sort, genotype)

importFrom(stats, na.omit)
importFrom(gdata, interleave, trim)
importFrom(mvtnorm, rmvnorm)
##importFrom(combinat, rmultz2) # combinat doesn't have a namesspace.
importFrom(gtools, binsearch, combinations, permutations)
```

### What is the difference between export and S3method? What do they do?

I notice that `LD` is both exported and registered with `S3method`, why is this necessary?